# How do you ignore volumes in lsof?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

When I run `lsof` I get this warning:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() smbfs file system /Volumes/.timemachine/DS920._smb._tcp.local/D218965D-0155-4757-AB63-B9036A3B29C8/Time Machine Backup - MyName
      Output information may be incomplete.
      assuming "dev=34000202" from mount table
```

I found [lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171519/348595) on Unix & Linux SE, but the suggested solution to use the `-e` option doesn't work on macOS as it is only implemented for Linux:

```
       +|-e s   exempts the file system whose path name is s from being subjected
                to kernel function calls that might block...

                This option is currently implemented only for Linux.
```

I know you can use `-w` to suppress warnings, but I only want to suppress this one warning, not any other potential warnings.

Is there a way to exclude my Time Machine volume from `lsof` or otherwise silence this warning without having to do something like `lsof 2>&1 1>/dev/null | grep -Ev "can't stat\(\) smbfs file system /Volumes/.timemachine|Output information may be incomplete\.|assuming \"dev=\\d+\" from mount table"`?

Comment: It clearly states: "This option is currently implemented only for Linux." In the interim, try disconnecting from your **Time Machine** volume before running `lsof`.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes I am aware it's not implemented for macOS; that's why I included that section of the man page.